# php ldap_search(): Search: Operations error

Tags: php, ldap

I try to connect to LDAP in PHP with this code :

```
$ds = ldap_connect("122.134.124.2", 389);
$login = "login@domain.local";
$password = "password";

if ($ds) 
{
    $r = ldap_bind($ds, $login, $password);
    $sr = ldap_search($ds, "dc=domain,dc=local", "cn=m*");    
}
else
    echo "Impossible to connect to the LDAP server.";
```

And I get this error :
***ldap_search(): Search: Operations error in test.php on line 8*** (the line with the ldap_search function).

Yet the connection works and I put all the parameters of the function ldap_search.

Comment: Did you see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6222836/1612146)?

Comment: Thank you. So the solution was to add these lines to the code : `ldap_set_option($ldap, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);
ldap_set_option($ldap, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);`

Comment: Noting that these lines must go BEFORE the bind call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to add these lines to the code : ldap_set_option($ldap, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0); ldap_set_option($ldap, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);